# Clicking on a vote number does not split into up and down vote counts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, votes

On SO, clicking on the number of votes a question or answer has causes it to split into separate up and down vote counts. This is not done here on unix.stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a privilege that you receive when you get to the 1000 point level. But you can install this browser plugin to unlock it on all SE sites.

- [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep/4112#4112)

#### References

- [Why can't I click on the up/down vote counter to see how the breakdown looks?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/why-cant-i-click-on-the-up-down-vote-counter-to-see-how-the-breakdown-looks?newreg=d418bdd629b44888bccc38ad9f64d990)

Comment: [Link to the privilege](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - thanks, I couldn't find that link.